# service principal does not have secrets get permission on key vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create a keyvault on Azure using Terraform which is performed by my service principal user:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                        = "${var.project_name}-keyvault"
  location                    = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "access_policy" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set", "Get", "Delete", "Purge", "List",  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_id" {
  name         = "client-id"
  value        = var.client_id_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_secret" {
  name         = "client-secret"
  value        = var.client_secret_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "subscription_id" {
  name         = "subscription-id"
  value        = var.subscription_id_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tenant_id" {
  name         = "tenant-id"
  value        = var.tenant_id_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}
```

But i get this error:

```
    Error: checking for presence of existing Secret "client-id" (Key Vault "https://formulaeinsdef-keyvault.vault.azure.net/"): keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret:
    Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: 
    Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=32d24355-0d93-476d-a775-6882d5a22e0b;iss=https://sts.windows.net/***/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'formulaeinsdef-keyvault;location=westeurope'. 
For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}
```

The above code creates the key-vault successfully, but it fails to add the secrets inside it.
My Service Principal user has Contributor role and i think, it should be enough to GET and SET key keys.

I tried to give my service principal the `Reader` or even `Owner`permission, but it was not helpful.

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111391/terraform-azure-keyvault-setsecret-forbidden-access-denied), but it is not helping me.
I checked the `Access Policies` tab and i have the permissions to Set, Get, Delete, Purge, List.

[image]

Comment: You would need to work with access policies and grant appropriate permissions to your Service Principal to work with keys and secrets. You can do so by visiting "Access configuration" tab in the KeyVault account in the Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the secrets needs an explicit dependency on the access policy. Otherwise, Terraform may attempt to create the secret before creating the access policy.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_id" {
  name         = "client-id"
  value        = var.client_id_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id

  ### Explicit dependency
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.access_policy
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, moving the access policy definition into the key vault block would make the explicit dependencies unnecessary:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  # Content omitted for brevity
  .
  .
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set", "Get", "Delete", "Purge", "List",  ]
  }
}
```